# What is the difference between an API-Gateway and an Edge Service?

Tags: microservices

I understand the concept behind an API gateway as described by Richardson:

http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

But what is the difference to an Edge service. Is this a concrete implementation of the API gateway pattern?

Answer (score 14):

Technically, an **API Gateway** is the API exposed to the public (REST, etc.), and an **Edge Service** is a service running on the API resolving the proxying, routing, etc. There could be many edge services on the Gateway. But practically there is usually only one service, logic, on the Gateway thus API Gateway = Edge Service.